# Perl 'My' Variable [$] makes earlier declaration in same statement

Tags: perl, debugging, warnings

So I have a few sub rutines for opening a file:

```
828 sub open_for_r {
829     my $FH = shift;
830     my $filename = shift;
831 
832     open($FH, "< $filename") || die "cannot open $filename: $!";
833 }
834 
835 sub open_for_w {
836     my $FH = shift;
837     my $filename = shift;
838 
839     open($FH, "> $filename") || die "cannot open $filename: $!";
840     # open($FH, ">> $filename") || die "cannot open $filename: $!";
841 }
842 
843 sub open_for_rw {
844     my $FH = shift;
845     my $filename = shift;
846 
847     open($FH, "+< $filename") || die "cannot open $filename: $!";
848     # open($FH, ">> $filename") || die "cannot open $filename: $!";
849 
850 }
851 
852 sub read_file {
853 
854     my $FH = shift;
855     my $filename = shift;
856     my $contents = "";
857     my $var = "";
858 
859     #To read from that file
860     while (defined($var = <$FH>)) {
861         # chomp($var);
862         # print "$var\n";
863     $contents .= $var;
864     }
865     return $contents;
866 }
```

Now I am getting a warning:

**"my" variable $FH masks earlier declaration in same scope at ittp_to_scn.pl line 836.**

**"my" variable $filename masks earlier declaration in same scope at ittp_to_scn.pl line 837.**

**"my" variable $FH masks earlier declaration in same scope at ittp_to_scn.pl line 844.**

**"my" variable $filename masks earlier declaration in same scope at ittp_to_scn.pl line 845.**

Although nowhere else in my code do I have the **$FH** or **$filename** declared. I don't understand why it is saying that there is an earlier declaration? Aren't I allowed to use the same variable names in different sub routines? Or is this not allowed in Perl?

Comment: Search for `$FH` before line 836. It's probably declared in the outermost scope somewhere. Or, you're missing a `}` at the end of the first sub.

Comment: Well I copy pasted my code into here so if there isn't a missing `}` here then its not missing in my code. Also I just searched and there are 0 other `$FH` or `$filename` variables anywhere in my code....

Comment: When I copy&paste your code and remove the numbers, I'm getting no errors. Is there a source filter involved?

Comment: And you don't get these warnings for lines 829, 830, 854, & 855?

Comment: Hmmm I turned on `use strict` fixed up some errors and now the warning is gone.

Comment: With the best will in the world - that's why `use strict;` and `use warnings;` are near mandatory before posting to stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got this warning today and I **DID** have

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

enabled.

I went through the code looking for missing `;` and extraneous `{`s and `}`s and found a superfluous `}` a few lines above where the issue was at the end of a statement (but before the semicolon).

Answer (score -6):

Turned on `use strict` and fixed some warnings. So there was no issue, just other issues caused these warnings.